# Copy active row from one worksheet table to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have sheet 1 (formatted as table) and sheet 2 (formatted as table). I want to copy the active row from from sheet 1 to sheet 2. I have tried the below and its works well for normal range but not for sheets formatted as table.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lastrow As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    lastrow = Application.Max(4, .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    .Range("B" & lastrow).Resize(, 5).Value = _
        Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Resize(, 5).Value
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) does your table in sheet1 contains formulas or only values (in columns `B:F`)? 2) same question for table in sheet2 (in columns `A:G`)?

Comment: @simoco its only values from dropdown

Comment: am I correct, you need to copy cells from active row (columns B:F) to new row in table ojn sheet2 (columns A:G)?

Comment: @simoco yes that's correct!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim tblRow As ListRow
    Dim lastRow As Long

    If UCase(Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row)) <> "YES" Then Exit Sub

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
        'change Sheet3 to destination sheet - where you need to paste values

        If Not IsError(Application.Match(Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row), .Range("B:B"), 0)) Then Exit Sub

        Set tbl = .ListObjects(1)
        If tbl.Range(tbl.Range.Rows.Count, "B") = "" Then
            lastRow = Application.Min(tbl.Range(tbl.Range.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1, _
                    Application.Max(4, .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1))
        Else
            lastRow = tbl.ListRows.add.Range.Row
        End If

    End With
    tbl.Range(lastRow, "B").Resize(, 5).Value = _
            Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Resize(, 5).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: looks like the records are getting copied on the last plus 1 row of Sheet 3 (formatted as table). Say I have Sheet 3 formatted as table till 100 rows(Column A to G), the copied record is put on line 101. However Sheet 3 table is blank. Please let me know.

Comment: this works great! I actually wanted to modify the code slightly but looking at it i'm worried :). I wanted to check if Column F in Sheet 1(formatted as table) is set to "Yes" and then copy also ensure no duplicates in Sheet 3 if data already exists!!. This is looking complex to me with tables :)

Comment: The unique identifier for Sheet 1 and Sheet 3 is located in Column B in both sheets

Comment: omg! this works great!! Simoco could you please explain if possible. I'll learn :))

Comment: Sure:) 1) `If UCase(Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row)) <> "YES" Then Exit Sub` - it's easy - if col F in active row <>YES - do nothing and exit sub. `UCase` jsut transform "yes", "Yes" and so on to upper case. 2) `If Not IsError(Application.Match(Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row), .Range("B:B"), 0)) Then Exit Sub` - try to find col B from active row in sheet3 col B. Match returns error if nothing found and row number is duplicate found. So if there is no error - there is a duplicate - do nothing and exit sub. 3) `Set tbl = .ListObjects(1)` just get table object in sheet3

Comment: _continue.._ 4) for finding lastrow there is a some problems. At first we should check if last row _in table_ is empty or not. If it's not empty - we add new row. If it's empty we tries to find lastrow (it's hard to explain this expression). Single part `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1)` doesn't work, because it's always stops in edge of table (actually we can remove this part, and use only `lastRow = Application.Max(4, tbl.Range(tbl.Range.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1)`. I leave it just for reliability). 5) copy desired range in last row

Comment: Wow thanks!! u make it really simple here. genius!!! I cant even vote for your previous post!!

Comment: I have modified the code slightly to display message that 1)Display message that row is not set to "Yes" 2) Display message that record already exist with Yes, No button. No does not copy but "Yes" will duplicate 3) Display message at end "Record copied". I cant post my code here as the lines are not enough. But my code is throwing error :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49980/discussion-between-simoco-and-user3331363)